# R: split dataframe column of proteomics data at specific character positions

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split

I want to split one column of my data frame in R into multiple ones. The table$Description of the proteomics data has many rows that look like the following:

```
Vimentin OS=Homo sapiens GN=VIM PE=1 SV=4
```

It would be great to split this table$Description into 5 separate columns named "protein", "OS", "GN", "PE" and "SV".

I tried the following:

`separate(table, Description, c("protein","OS","GN","PE","SV"),sep = c(' OS=',' GN=',' PE=',' SV='), convert = TRUE)`

The output only fills the protein and OS column, but the others are filled with N/A. 
The error message is the following:

```
1: In stringi::stri_split_regex(value, sep, n_max) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: Expected 5 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 11149 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...].
```

Does anyone know how to adjust the code?

Answer (score 1):

Your example contains only one string. So I am not sure if the following works for your data. But here is my attempt.

```
mydf <- tibble(id = 1:2,
               text = c("Vimentin OS=Homo sapiens GN=VIM PE=1 SV=4",
                        "Vimentin OS=Homo sapiens GN=VIM PE=2 SV=8"))

separate(mydf, col = text, into = c("Protein", "OS","GN","PE","SV"),
         sep = "\\s(?=[A-Z])") %>% 
mutate_at(vars(OS:SV),
        .funs = list(~sub(x = ., pattern = "^[A-Z]{2}=", replacement = "")))

#    id Protein  OS           GN    PE    SV   
#  <int> <chr>    <chr>        <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 Vimentin Homo sapiens VIM   1     4    
#2     2 Vimentin Homo sapiens VIM   2     8
```

**Update**

Since you said that your real data has different nature, I created pseudo data. I hope this is similar enough to what you have. In Row 2 and 3, some information is missing while Row 1 has everything as you previously described. I split the text with `stri_split_regex()`. Then, for each list, I basically created and assigned names to the vector in the list. Then, I created a data frame using `stack()`. After `map_dfr()`, I trimmed first two capital letters and = in the column, `values`. Finally, I converted the data to a wide-format data. I hope this is enough for you.

```
mydf <- tibble(id = 1:3,
               text = c("Vimentin OS=Homo sapiens GN=VIM PE=1 SV=4",
                        "Vimentin OS=Homo sapiens GN=VIM PE=2",
                        "Vimentin OS=Homo sapiens PE=1 SV=4"))

     id text                                                                         
1     1 Vimentin OS=Homo sapiens GN=VIM PE=1 SV=4
2     2 Vimentin OS=Homo sapiens GN=VIM PE=2     
3     3 Vimentin OS=Homo sapiens PE=1 SV=4
```

Here is what I tried.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

stri_split_regex(str = mydf$text, pattern = "\\s(?=[A-Z])") %>% 
map_dfr(.f = function(x){
               # Get OS, GN, PE, and SV
               foo <- stri_extract_all_regex(str = x, pattern = "^[A-Z]{2}") %>%
                      unlist %>% 
                      .[complete.cases(.)]

               # Now create names for the vector
               mynames <- c("Protein", foo)

               # Assign the names to the vector
               names(x) <- mynames

               stack(x)},

        .id = "id") %>% 
mutate(values = sub(x = values, pattern = "^[A-Z]{2}=", replacement = "")) %>% 
pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = ind, values_from = values,
           values_fill = list(values = NA)) 

#  id    Protein  OS           GN    PE    SV   
#  <chr> <chr>    <chr>        <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 1     Vimentin Homo sapiens VIM   1     4    
#2 2     Vimentin Homo sapiens VIM   2     NA   
#3 3     Vimentin Homo sapiens NA    1     4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have now rewritten the code:

separate(table, Description, 
                 c("protein","OS","GN","PE","SV"),sep = " [A-Z]{2}=")

It is working for all the rows where OS, GN, PE and SV are defined in the description. Now I realized that some rows don't contain information for e.g. GN and the separate function does not work correctly there

Comment: @JanineLux How your data look like then? Can you provide some examples as you did in your question?

Comment: @JanineLux I created a pseudo data. Have a look and see if you can take any from this and work on your project.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The data looks like this, except for that there is no id column, but lots of others after the one labelled text in your example.

Somehow, when I try this approach, there is the following error:
Error in names(x) <- mynames:
'names' attribute [6] must be the same length as the vector [5]

Comment: @JanineLux It is clear that sting patterns you have are different from the pattern I created. That naming part is creating names for vector elements. The error message is telling you that the number of vector elements and the number of names are not matching. If you can share the data, I am happy to have a look. Otherwise, there is not much I can help from this point.

Answer (score 0):

Not the nicest looking code, but for a base R option we can try splitting the string on the following pattern:

```
\s+[^= ]+=
```

This will consume all keys, leaving behind only the five values you want.  Then, we can convert to a data frame, transpose, and finally apply the column names.

```
df <- data.frame(t(data.frame(sapply(df$Description, function(x) strsplit(x, "\\s+[^= ]+=")))))
names(df) <- c("protein", "OS", "GN", "PE", "SV")
df

                                             protein           OS  GN PE SV
Vimentin.OS.Homo.sapiens.GN.VIM.PE.1.SV.4   Vimentin Homo sapiens VIM  1  4
Vimentin.OS.Homo.sapiens.GN.VIM.PE.1.SV.4.1 Vimentin Homo sapiens VIM  1  4
```

**Data:**

```
x <- "Vimentin OS=Homo sapiens GN=VIM PE=1 SV=4"
df <- data.frame(Description=c(x,x), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```